# How-to exclude classes from classpath using distribution gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle v7.4 and `distribution` plugin and code like following

```
// All these code located in module AB
abstract class AbstractClass {
  // common code that is using by child-classes
}

class ClassA extends AbstractClass {
  // logic #1 uses code from moduleA
}

class ClassB extends AbstractClass {
  // logic #2 uses code from moduleB
}
```

`build.gradle` in module AB looks following

```
plugins {
  ...
  id 'distribution'
}

...

distributions {

  zipFileA {
    distributionBaseName = "fileA"
    contents {
      with project.distributions.main.getContents()
      exclude {
        it.name.startsWith("neccessary-modules") && !it.name.contains("moduleA")
      }
  }

  zipFileB {
    distributionBaseName = "fileB"
    contents {
      with project.distributions.main.getContents()
      exclude {
        it.name.startsWith("neccessary-modules") && !it.name.contains("moduleB")
      }
  }
}
```

The main idea is to get in result ZIP files with all needed classes. File `fileA.zip` should not have any code related to B; the same for `fileB.zip` - should not contain code related to A.

Is it possible to achieve that by `distribution` Gradle plugin?